# Loop the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

(**I added jsfiddle since Stack snippet is down**): https://jsfiddle.net/5xopbujL/

I broke my head trying to fix the scrip working. I have the following simple javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  showMessage();
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".msg-content").empty();
    showMessage();
  }, 7000);
})
```

```css
:root {
  --msg-content-height: 26.75em;
  --msg-spacing: 1em;
  --msg1-height: 5.5em;
  --msg2-height: 4em;
  --msg3-height: 2.5em;
  --msg4-height: 2.5em;
  --msg5-height: 4em;
  --msg6-height: 3.25em;
}

.msg-send {
  position: absolute;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.msg-receive {
  position: absolute;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  background-color: #2d67ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.msg-container {
  width: 28em;
}

.msg-content {
  height: var(--msg-content-height);
}


/*Animation Names*/

#msg1 {
  animation-name: msg1;
}

#msg2 {
  animation-name: msg2;
}

#msg3 {
  animation-name: msg3;
}

#msg4 {
  animation-name: msg4;
}

#msg5 {
  animation-name: msg5;
}

#msg6 {
  animation-name: msg6;
}


/*Key Frames*/

@keyframes msg1 {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height));
    left: -4em;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  5% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height));
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  12% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height));
  }
  17% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height));
  }
  30% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height));
  }
  35% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height));
  }
  49% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height));
  }
  54% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  70% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  75% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes msg2 {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height));
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  12% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height));
    right: -4em;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  17% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height));
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height));
  }
  35% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height));
  }
  49% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height));
  }
  54% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  70% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  75% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
    right: 0;
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg6-height));
    right: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes msg3 {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height));
    left: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  30% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height));
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  35% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height));
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  49% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height));
  }
  54% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  70% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  75% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
    left: 0;
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg6-height));
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes msg4 {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height));
    right: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  49% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height));
    right: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  54% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height));
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  75% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
    right: 0;
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg6-height));
    right: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes msg5 {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg5-height));
    left: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  70% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg5-height));
    left: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  75% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg5-height));
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg5-height));
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg5-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg6-height));
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes msg6 {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg6-height));
    right: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg6-height));
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg6-height));
    right: 0em;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="msg-container pv4 ph4 br3 center bg-white shadow-6">
  <div class="msg-content w-100 relative">
    <div id="msg1" class="msg-receive dib mb4 bg-message br4 pv2 ph3 white measure-narrow">Message #1</div>
    <div id="msg2" class="msg-send dib mb4 bg-near-white br4 pv2 ph3 mid-gray measure-narrow">Message #2 </div>
    <div id="msg3" class="msg-receive dib mb4 bg-message br4 pv2 ph3 white measure-narrow">Message #3</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Everything is almost fine but I can't find a way how to hide the "message" block as soon as it reaches the `--msg-content-height` . And how to loop the messages? So how to make the messages disappear when they reaches the top and loop them?

Comment: The stack snippet is not down, you just didn't add the `showMessage()` function.

Comment: Hello @mark-baijens , Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Comment: You asked this two hours ago already, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224959/loop-the-messages-in-script Please do not create such duplicates! (You could have still added the fiddle to your existing question by editing it.)

Comment: @astonearachnid maybe it would be better to mark that first question as duplicate, because here someone answered...

Comment: @Jamdev, I do not get such error. Also you did seem to be able to provide a snippet so I don't see the problem. Just edit the snippet with the needed code.

Answer (score 0):

If you listen for each message when the animation has ended, you can remove it. It's useful however for demo purposes, to include a delay for consecutive messages.
You may have to adjust the percentages of the keyframes.

```js
$('#msg1, #msg2, #msg3').on('animationend', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
#msg1 {
  animation-name: msg1;
}

#msg2 {
  animation-name: msg2;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

#msg3 {
  animation-name: msg3;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```